# create multiple arrays from SQL dataset in classic ASP for HighCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, asp-classic, highcharts

I want to know how I can split this dataset into multiple arrays to use as datasets in a HighCharts Line chart

below resultSet(0,i) contains a date and 
 resultSet(1,i) contains a value.

I want to be able to depending on the year of the date;

Year(resultSet(0,i)) break out the dataset into multiple datasets for a HighCharts Line Chart. basically something like

```vbs
if recordDate = Year(resultSet(0,i)) then
           ''populate recordSet1
    recordSet1(i) = resultSet(1,i)
else
          'if the records now have a new date
          'add a year to the recordDate, since they are in chronological order in the resultset
   recordDate = recordDate + 1 
           'do the check on that record now and add it to a new resultSet, then re-enter the loop and populate the new recordSet
    if recordDate = Year(resultSet(0,i)) then
          recordSet2(i) = resultSet(1,i)
    end if
End If
```

but I can't think of how to create array names dynamically so that I can have multiple record sets.

```vbs
'Get CurrentYear to Compare Dataset To
dim CurrentYear
CurrentYear = Year(Date)

dim totalYears
dim recordDate
    totalYears = (adoRsChart("yr_count") - 1)
    recordDate = CurrentYear - totalYears
dim dateYearDiff
dim yAxisData()
dim xAxisData()
dim resultSet 
resultSet = adoRsChart.GetRows()

For i = 0 to UBound(resultSet, 2)
    reDim preserve xAxisData(i)
    xAxisData(i) = resultSet(1,i)
    response.write(resultSet(0,i) & "<br/>")
    response.write(resultSet(1,i) & "<br/>")
    response.write(resultSet(2,i) & "<br/>")
    response.write(resultSet(3,i) & "<br/>")
    reDim preserve yAxisData(i)
    yAxisData(i) = "'" &  resultSet(3,i) & "'"
Next
```

Comment: Would a loop within a loop help? That way you could have multiple record sets and not worry about dynamically creating names

Comment: How your data/series looks like in output? It is a json or you print a text?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually have an array of arrays...

```
chartData(i,j)(k)
```

... but I really wouldn't recommend it. Apart from the "can't wrap my brain around it" problems, this is an easy way to run out of memory on the server.

Can you generate the charts within the loop, i.e. just re-use the same variables?